# FlipClock counter обратный отсчет каждый день

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой таймер [flipclock](http://flipclockjs.com/) на странице:

```js
var clock;
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter', //вид счетчика (с количеством дней)
    autoStart: false,          //Отключаем автозапуск
    countdown: true ,           //Отсчет назад
    language:'ru-ru',           //Локаль языка
    callbacks: {               //Действие после окончания отсчета
    stop: function() {
  
        }
       }
    });
  
clock.setTime(3600 * 24);        //Устанавливаем нужное время в секундах
clock.setCountdown(true); //Устанавливаем отсчет назад
clock.start();           //Запускаем отсчет
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="clock"></div>
```

Но проблема в том, что нужен отсчет без дней, а с 24:00 до 00:00 каждый день. Т.е. таймер доходит до 00:00 и опять начинает заново. Нужно ли для этого `localStorage` если в режиме реального времени (в 20:00 получается должен отображать 04:00 , осталось 4 часа как например). Как можно допилить код?

Если такой пример:

```js
var clock;
clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 5, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter', //вид счетчика (с количеством дней)
    autoStart: true,          //Отключаем автозапуск
    countdown: true ,           //Отсчет назад
    language:'ru-ru',           //Локаль языка
    callbacks: {               //Действие после окончания отсчета
        stop: function() {
          clock.setTime(5);  
          clock.setCountdown(true);
          clock.start(); 
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="clock"></div>
```

То я так понимаю не будет работать как положено, потому как уже второй отсчет почему-то не с 5, а с 3-х секунд идет. И автозапуск работает с момента обновления страницы, а нужно не зависимо от обновления чтобы таймер работал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде, чем инициализировать таймер, нужно высчитать `86400 - x = y`, где 86400 - кол-во секунд в сутках, `x` - текущее время в секундах, `y` - кол-во секунд до 00:00.

Далее "запускаем" таймер с полученным `y`, а в `callback`'e уже запускаем его заново со значением в `86400`.

```js
Data = new Date();
var time = 86400 - (Data.getHours()*3600 + Data.getMinutes()*60 + Data.getSeconds());
console.log(time);
var clock;
clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), time, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter', //вид счетчика (с количеством дней)
    autoStart: true,          //Отключаем автозапуск
    countdown: true ,           //Отсчет назад
    language:'ru-ru',           //Локаль языка
    callbacks: {               //Действие после окончания отсчета
        stop: function() {
          clock.setTime(86400);  
          clock.setCountdown(true);
          clock.start(); 
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!